# No asigna propiedad (undefined) en Angular

Tags: angular

Les cuento amigos. Estoy viendo un tema con Angular pero no conozco muy bien lo que corresponde al traspaso de datos entre componentes para ser enviados por formulario, lo que me tiene entrampado.

De momento tengo un componente el cual se encarga de enviar notificaciones a mails.

En lo que respecta al componente html tengo un boton de tipo switch que activaria o desactivaria un valor true para indicar si esa notificacion se envia de manera inmediata o bien despues.

[image: boton]

Por otro lado en su archivo .ts tengo el metodo OnChangeInmediata que recibiria ese parametro y se lo asignaria a una variable de tipo bolean que existe en un modelo llamado Notificacion2

```js
    import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import {FormControl} from "@angular/forms";
    import { SelectionType } from '@swimlane/ngx-datatable';
    import {MedidaCautelar} from "../../../../../../models/nomenclatura";
    import {Notificacion2} from "../../../../../../models/notificacion";
    
    interface LitiganteCorreo{
      nombre:string,
      correo:string
    }
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-cautelar-notificaciones',
      templateUrl: './cautelar-notificaciones.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./cautelar-notificaciones.component.scss']
    })
    
    export class CautelarNotificacionesComponent implements OnInit {
    
      @Input() medidaCautelar: MedidaCautelar = null;
      
      public notificacion: Notificacion2;
    
      public envioInmediata:boolean = false;
         
    
      public correos: string[] = [];
      public validators = [this.validarEmail];
      public errorMessages = {
        'validarEmail': 'Ingrese un E-mail válido!'
      };
      public SelectionType = SelectionType;
      public mostrarScrollHorizontal:boolean = false;
      public mostrarScrollVertical:boolean = false;
      public correosLitigantesSel: LitiganteCorreo[] = [];
      public correosLitigantes: LitiganteCorreo[]= [
        {nombre: 'JUAN ', correo: 'juan@correo.cl'},
        {nombre: 'CARLOS', correo: 'carlos@correo.cl'},
        {nombre: 'PEDRO', correo: 'pedro@correo.cl'}
      ];
    
    
      constructor() { }
    
      ngOnInit() {
      }
    
      private validarEmail(control: FormControl) {
        const EMAIL_REGEXP = /^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~.-]+@[a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?(\.[a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)*$/i;
        if (control.value != "" && (control.value.length <= 5 || !EMAIL_REGEXP.test(control.value))) {
          return {"validarEmail": true};
        }
        return null;
      }
      public seleccionaCorreoLitigante(correo: LitiganteCorreo){
        console.log('SELECCIONADO', correo);
      }
    
    
    
      public onChangeInmediata(check:boolean):void{
        this.envioInmediata = true;
        this.notificacion.flgInmediata = check;
        //console.log(this.notificacion.flgInmediata);
      }
    
    
    
    }
```

Al presionar el boton switch, me arroja este error, y no logro dar con su problema. Habra algo que se me este olvidando en estos archivos o bien desde otros?. PD: Existe la variable en el model.

[image: error]

Answer (score 0):

Intenta cambiando:

```
public notificacion: Notificacion2;
```

con:

```
public notificacion = new Notificacion2();
```

Así creas una instancia del componente.

Saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, intente con ello pero no me funciono, me boto toda la compilacion, supongo pues estoy declarando una variable publica notificacion de tipo Notificacion2 que seria la clase del componente, pero que no es en si un metodo o no funciona como tal, creo.

Comment: Ok perfecto! y si lo pones dentro del constructor de la clase  CautelarNotificacionesComponenta a: 
public notificacion: Notificacion2;
??